# How can I post my data that i get from SQL into divs in php

Tags: php, html, css, sql

I need to make a page that shows posts from database. It has to have a Title and text in the post. I get all of the information from database already, but I don't know how to make it so they are placed into divs. Currently the data I get is set into tables, but I would like to get them into divs. Current code: (note: I have the php and sql connection working)

```
$sql = "SELECT title, txt FROM xxxxx";
$result = $con->query($sql);

   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    echo "<table><tr><th>Title</th><th>Text</th></tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["title"]. "</td><td>" . $row["txt"]. " </td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Also by that I was looking for bootstrap panel-group classes, but I was not able to implement that.

Comment: And what is not working?

Comment: It has to be in divs, currently it's just a table that is not looking very good. Is there a possibility to make it so everytime someone submits a post, it automaticly shows up on the page as a div with a heading class and text class?

Comment: It looks like you haven't even tried to put it into divs. The code is right there.

Comment: Yes in the code above I haven't, but everything I tried so far has failed with divs and I only got errors. That's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: change table for div in line 6 and 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you forgot to include your divs:

```
   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    echo "<div><table><tr><th>Title</th><th>Text</th></tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["title"]. "</td><td>" . $row["txt"]. " </td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table></div>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

or if you don't want to include a table but only the divs, simply do it like so:

```
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    echo "<div class='title'><h1>Title</h1>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<p>" . $row["title"]. "</p><p>" . $row["txt"]. " </p>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, almost what I was hoping for but currently every title and text is between <p> that, but I'd like to have it so when users submits something I get a div that has a div class heading (title) that has the background color gray (for example) and a text div class, so I can style them with css.

<div class="panel-group" >
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
<div class="panel-body"></div>

Comment: Well you can include a class in your div in order to manipulate with your css. Also the <p> tags can manipulated easily by your div class. I updated my answer and included a class.

Comment: Thank you very much, Nikolas!